# Can we use iPod front or rear camera to stop an event using it's change in brightness?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have develop an application from the ipod touch 4 but unfortunately it doesnt occupy a proximity sensor, But i want to start and stop a certain event by triggering the brightness of the camera, Is this possible to implement? if so, does it consumes more CPU? and also Can i use both cameras?